# Handle transaction when invoking SQL stored procedure in side a C# loop

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

I'm working on a system which is already developed by some other developers.
And in that system they have invoked a stored procedure which use to insert records in side a loop in C# without using User define table types.

And what I need to do is to add a transaction to this scenario. But the problem is I have no idea about the place to have the transaction.

I would like to know whether have it in the C# code warping up the loop or inside the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have it inside the C# loop. A transaction started inside the procedure *must* commit before the procedures exits. SQL Server checks the [`@@TRANCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx) before and after running a procedure and if the results don't match an exception is raised. So is impossible for a procedure to start a transaction that has to be committed by caller.

The easiest think to do is to wrap your C# code in a transaction scope:

```
using(var scope =  new TransactionScope(
      TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
      new TransactionOptions() {
         IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
      })) {
   // Do the work here
   scope.Complete();
}
```

Note that passing the `IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted` is [**critical**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2010/06/03/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 1):

In this case Transaction needs to begin in the C# code, you have following options:

- Use the `Transaction` from the `Connection object`:

  ```
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
  {
  conn.Open();
  using (IDbTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
  {
      try
      {
          // transactional code...
          using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
          {
              // Loop the Insert operation here 
              cmd.CommandText = "INSERT Operation";
              cmd.Transaction = tran as SqlTransaction;
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
          tran.Commit();
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          tran.Rollback();
          throw;
      }
  }
  }
  ```
- Use `Implicit or Explicit Ambient transaction`
- Use `TransactionScope` (Implicit) Ambient transaction (On Exception it's an automatic rollback)

  ```
  using (var scope =  new TransactionScope(
       TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
       new TransactionOptions() {
       IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
     }))
  {
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
  {
     conn.Open();

      using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
      {
          // Loop the Insert operation here 
          cmd.CommandText = "INSERT Operation";
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }                
  }    
   scope.Complete();
  }
  ```

  - Use `CommittableTransaction` (Explicit) Ambient transaction

    ```
    var tran = new CommittableTransaction();
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
     conn.Open();
    try
    {
       conn.EnlistTransaction(tran);

    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        // Loop the Insert operation here 
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT Operation";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }   
      tran.Commit();
    }   
    catch(Exception ex)
     {
        tran.Rollback();
        throw;
     }          
    }
    ```

For `Ambient transactions`, please remember that if you open more than one connection, then it will get promoted from `local to global transaction`, thus requiring `MSDTC` and that has a performance impact.

Check the following link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690136/All-About-TransactionScope

Answer (score 0):

In SQL SERVER

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN 

-- DO YOUR INSERT /UPDATE /DELETE HERE 

COMMIT TRAN T1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
-- // ROLL BACK IF ERROR OCCURS

ROLLBACK TRAN T1
END CATCH
```

In C#

```
using(TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope()) {

     // DO YOUR INSERT /UPDATE /DELETE HERE 

    tran.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Both (Sql Server, C#) would be same only when all inserts / DML take place in same transaction context, which is not the case here since the inserts are multiple round trip. For both to be same it needs to be using TVP